# i want to find two value from selected month and year using SQL select query

Tags: php, mysql

[Click here For Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if28I.png)

Here is my select query:

```
/* First query */
SELECT YEAR, SUM( amount ) AS total
FROM accounts
WHERE ((MONTH >=  '10' || 
        MONTH <=  '12' && YEAR =  '2015') && 
       (MONTH >=  '1' || 
        MONTH <=  '3' && YEAR =  '2016'))
GROUP BY YEAR

/* Second query */
SELECT YEAR, SUM( amount ) AS total
FROM accounts
WHERE ((MONTH >=  '1' || 
        MONTH <=  '3' && YEAR =  '2015') &&
       (MONTH >=  '5' || 
        MONTH <=  '10' && YEAR =  '2015'))
GROUP BY YEAR
```

The first query will return the total amount over two rows which is exactly what I want, but if the user selects month in second query, then it will only return one row but I need two rows based on the where condition.

Please help me.

Comment: Please look at this article to improve the question: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Show sample data and desired output.  Your question is a bit vague as it currently stands.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific SQL there...)

Comment: @jarlh I'm assuming MySQL since he's using PHP.

Comment: pure php with codeigniter

Comment: Most probably MySQL, so why not add that tag?

Comment: i attach image on title so you can see output which is give me one row but i want two row base on where condition